# If $S=\{a \in \mathbb{R^+}: a \ne1\}$ with binary operation * defined by $a*b=a^{\ln(b)}$. What is the inverse of $a$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

To first solve for the identity, I did:

$a*e=a^{\ln(e)}=a$

$e*a=e^{\ln(a)}=a$

So in both cases, I'm unable to solve for $e$. Would this simply mean that there's no identity in the set? And so it follows that there's no way that any element in the set has an inverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means $e \approx 2.718 \ldots $ is the identity in this group as you have shown in your question.  I think you think $e$ is the symbol for identity, but it is Euler's number, the base of the natural logarithm.  This looks like the inverse of $a$ is $e^{\frac{1}{\ln(a)}}$

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing "$e$" as denoting Euler's constant (which is relevant) and "$e$" as denoting the operative identity (which *might* be Euler's constant but we can not assume that without proving).

Let's avoid the confusion.  Let's use,.... $z$ to mean the operative identity.

So for all $a$ then $a*z = a^{\ln z} = a$ for all $a$ and $z*a = z^{\ln a} = a$.

If $a \ne 1$ then $a^{m} = a \iff m = 1$ so $\ln z = 1$ so $z = $ Euler's constant.

And if $z^{\ln a} = a$ then $\ln (z^{\ln a}) = \ln a *\ln z = \ln a \implies \ln z = 1 \implies z = $ Euler's constant.

So the solution *IS* $z = e$.

So now you must find the inverse of $a$.  $a*a^{-1} = a^{\ln a^{-1}} = e$.

For a given $a$, if we are told that $a^{\ln m} = e$ what is the value of $m$?

Well, take the natural log of both sides....

$\ln a^{\ln m} = \ln e$

$\ln m* \ln a = 1$

$\ln m = \frac 1{\ln a}$

$m = e^{\ln m} = e^{\frac 1{\ln a}}$.

So ... that's it.  $a^{-1} = e^{\frac 1{\ln a}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let  C be the identity element 
Then  $$\ {c} \ast {a} = {a} \ast {c} = {a} $$
 $$\ {a} \ast {c} = {a}^{lnc} = {a} $$
 Taking logrithm to both sides 
$$\ (lna)(lnc) = (lna) $$
So we get $$\ c = e (Euler's  number) $$
If you do the same with $$\ {c} \ast {a} $$
You will get the same answer. Therefore now we have c(identity element)= e
Now for the inverse we need to have $$ {a} \ast {b} = {c} $$ where 'b' is the inverse 
Then by doing a bunch of simple calculation you will get $$\ {b} = {e}^{(\frac{1} {lna})} $$